# node error Cannot find module 'x' even though other modules found and is installed

Tags: node.js, npm, import, node-modules, package.json

In our node app we have 6 sub-folders for services, each with a package.json. and lock files, dockerfiles etc.

In sub-folder (let's call it A) A, we need postgres so we have 'pg' (v ^8.7.3) installed and a postgres.js file with all the setup. We are using this (pg) in 2 other sub-folders and they work without any issue.

The issue comes when I *import a function from the postgres.js file*, saying 'Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
Require Stack:
-/app/src/utils/postgres.js
-/app/src/index.js'
-etc

This happens only in sub-folder A.

We think it may have to do with either node/npm versioning, or a dependency like @mocha , @mocha-multi.

sub-folder A:
-node version: v20.9.0
-npm version: v10.1.0

App:
-node version: v10.1.0
-npm version: v20.9.0

We tried uninstalling the package and re-installing, same issue.

We tried deleting all import statements and re-entering them. I have attached a copy of the log of the error in our docker container [log of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ6OE.png), as well as the package.json and postgres.js files code.

postgres.js

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import config from 'config';
import assert from 'assert';

// const fs = require('fs');
// const path = require('path');

let pool;

const dbConfig = {
  host: config.get('postgres.host'),
  port: config.get('postgres.port'),
  database: config.get('postgres.dbName'),
  password: config.get('postgres.password'),
  user: config.get('postgres.user'),
  connectionTimeoutMillis: config.get('postgres.initialTimeout'),
  idleTimeoutMillis: config.get('postgres.idleTimeoutMillis'),
  max: config.get('postgres.maxPoolSize'),
};

/**
 * initPGConnection, initializes the connection to the postgres server
 */
export const initPGConnection = () => {
  try {
    pool = new Pool(dbConfig);
    console.info(`Connected to PG using host: ${dbConfig.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Issue initializing pg connection', error);
  }
};

/**
 * returns a initialized connection to the postgres server
 * @returns returns a initialized connection to the postgres server
 */
export const getPool = () => {
  assert.ok(pool, 'Postgress Connection need to get initialized first');
  return pool;
};

/**
 * Executes a Query to the postgres database
 * @param {String} query SQL Query to run
 * @param {List} parameters Set of parameters required in the query
 * @returns the result of the query
 */
export const runQuery = async (query, parameters) => {
  let result;
  console.info(query, parameters);
  try {
    assert.ok(pool, 'Postgress Connection need to get initialized first');
    result = await pool.query(query, parameters);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  return result;
};

export const closeConnection = () => pool?.end();
```

package.json of A:

```
{
  "name": "xxx-A",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d build --copy-files",
    "batch": "node src/batch.js",
    "fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test nyc ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require @babel/register --recursive \"test/**/*.test.js\" --timeout 100000 --exit",
    "testci": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/nyc ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -R mocha-multi --reporter-options spec=-,xunit=tests_output/spec/ingestor_tests.xml --require @babel/register --recursive \"test/**/*.test.js\" --timeout 50000 --exit || exit 0",
    "start-dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon --ignore './dropzone/' --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=staging node --experimental-modules build/index.js",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js.json,css,scss,md,html}\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "precommit": "npm run format && npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async-csv": "^2.1.3",
    "await-exec": "^0.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "core.js": "^0.4.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv": "^5.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.11.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "inotifywait": "^1.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "move-file": "^2.0.0",
    "object-hash": "^2.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "poller": "0.0.5",
    "striplines": "^1.0.2",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5",
    "winston-transport": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-codfish": "^5.4.1",
    "eslint-config-kentcdodds": "^14.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "lint-staged": "^10.3.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporters": "^1.23.6",
    "mocha-multi": "^1.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sinon": "^9.0.3"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "check-coverage": false,
    "per-file": true,
    "lines": 99,
    "statements": 99,
    "functions": 99,
    "branches": 99,
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "text",
      "cobertura",
      "html"
    ],
    "report-dir": "./tests_output/coverage"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,scss,html}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.md": [
      "prettier --write",
      "markdownlint"
    ],
    "*.js": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json of B:

```
{
  "name": "xxx-B",
  "description": "xxx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/index.js",
    "debug": "npm run dev",
    "dev:docker": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon --r dotenv/config --ignore 'dropzone/' --ignore 'seeds/' --exec babel-node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --ignore 'dropzone/' --ignore 'seeds/' --exec babel-node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 src/index.js",
    "build": "babel src -d build --copy-files",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require @babel/register --recursive \"test/**/*.spec.js\"  --timeout 100000 --exit",
    "testci": "NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha || exit 0",
    "node:hardhat": "npx hardhat node",
    "test:hardhat": "npx hardhat test --network docker --parallel",
    "compile:hardhat": "npx hardhat compile",
    "export-abi:hardhat": "npx hardhat export-abi",
    "fix": "npm run format && npm run lint -- --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,json,css,scss,md}\"",
    "format:sol": "prettier --write \"**/*.sol\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:md": "markdownlint --ignore node_modules **/*.md"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.13.16",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^12.1.4",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^12.1.4",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-web3": "^2.0.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^3.4.0",
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.11",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-bn": "^0.2.1",
    "chai-datetime": "^1.8.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-codfish": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.0",
    "hardhat-abi-exporter": "^2.8.0",
    "inline-css": "^3.0.0",
    "jshint": "^2.12.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "markdownlint-cli": "^0.27.1",
    "mocha": "^8.4.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "sha256-file": "^1.0.0",
    "sinon": "^11.1.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.4",
    "solhint": "^3.3.5",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.16",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "timekeeper": "^2.2.0",
    "truffle": "5.3.4",
    "truffle-assertions": "^0.9.2",
    "truffle-contract-size": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.37.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@kubernetes/client-node": "^0.16.2",
    "@opengsn/contracts": "^2.2.2",
    "@opengsn/provider": "^2.2.2",
    "async-csv": "^2.1.3",
    "await-exec": "^0.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clamscan": "^1.4.2",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^2.0.0",
    "csv": "^5.5.0",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "dapp-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "email-regex-safe": "^1.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-request-id": "^1.4.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.11.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "into-stream": "^6.0.0",
    "json5": "^2.2.0",
    "kafkajs": "^1.15.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.11",
    "mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2": "^1.0.42",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "morgan-body": "^2.6.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nocache": "^3.0.1",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "object-hash": "^2.1.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web3": "^1.7.0",
    "web3-eth-contract": "^1.3.6",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5",
    "winston-syslog": "^2.4.4",
    "winston-transport": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "check-coverage": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "produce-source-map": true,
    "per-file": true,
    "lines": 99,
    "statements": 99,
    "functions": 99,
    "branches": 99,
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "cobertura",
      "html"
    ],
    "report-dir": "./tests_output/coverage"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,scss,html}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.md": [
      "prettier --write",
      "markdownlint"
    ],
    "*.js": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```